# Proper way to use table alias in linked server update query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm attempting to write an update query that uses both a local server and a linked server (amazon web service sql server). I need to use a table alias in order to truncate my statements to 4 denominations or less, such as [Server].[Database].[TableAlias].[Column] instead of [Server].[Database].[Owner].[Table].[Column] so that the multi-part identifier can be bound.

This is the update query I am attempting to use table aliases with:

```
UPDATE [Amazon IP].[AmazonDatabase].dbo.InkVials
SET InkRequestID = Local_Database.dbo.TasksInkRequests.InkRequestID
FROM Local_Database.dbo.TasksInkRequests
WHERE [Amazon IP].[AmazonDatabase].dbo.InkVials.InkRequestID = Local_Database.dbo.TasksInkRequests.JobRequestID
AND [Amazon IP].[AmazonDatabase].dbo.InkVials.Processing = 1;
```

I've tried multiple ways but don't seem to be doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally how you use Table aliases to do an update with a joined table:

```
UPDATE i
SET InkRequestID = r.InkRequestID
FROM [Amazon IP].[AmazonDatabase].dbo.InkVials i
INNER JOIN Local_Database.dbo.TasksInkRequests r
  ON  i.InkRequestID = r.JobRequestID
WHERE i.Processing = 1;
```

Comment: this worked. I'm unsure exactly how it worked myself, but it worked great.